# Write to storage with assembly inline

Tags: storage, assembly

I have this contract where I use inline assembly to add two numbers.

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract Test {
    function add(uint a, uint b) external {
        assembly {
            let sum := add(a,b)
            mstore(mload(0x40), sum)
        }
    } 
}
```

Now the question is, how to write variable `sum` to storage? In other words, how to make this `sum` persistent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following line at the end of your assembly -

```
sstore(value.slot, sum)
```

That will store `sum` value into the slot of contract variable `value`.

You can also remove the `mstore` and local var `sum` and write directly to the variable -

```
contract Test {

    uint256 public value;

    function add(uint a, uint b) external {
        assembly {
            sstore(value.slot, add(a,b))
        }
    } 
}
```

Take into consideration this doesn't handle arithmetic overflow, this is not safe to use if input number `a + b` is larger than `uint256`.

Comment: So its not possible to allocate a storage slot within inline assembly code?\

Comment: I think you can do that, can read about it here https://jeancvllr.medium.com/solidity-tutorial-all-about-assembly-5acdfefde05c

Comment: I think this is how you do it.  let x := add(a,b), sstore(0, x). So no need for 
uint256 public value;